# collisionDetection doesn't match css animation

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

I'm making a very basic space invaders game, but having some trouble with the collisionDetection. `enemy` are the ones I need to hit, they are inside `"fiende"`. `"missile"` is the div for the missiles.

I haven't tried much, since I'm very new to js, hence I don't have enough knowledge to improve on it.

EDIT: After some testing, I've found out that the collisionDetection breaks when the animations is running.

```
function collisionDetection() {
    for (var enemy = 0; enemy < fiende.length; enemy++) {
        for (var missile = 0; missile < missiles.length; missile++) {
            if (
                missiles[missile].left >= fiende[enemy].left &&
                missiles[missile].left <= (fiende[enemy].left + 50) &&
                missiles[missile].top <= (fiende[enemy].top + 50) &&
                missiles[missile].top >= fiende[enemy].top
            ) {
                fiende.splice(enemy, 1);
                missiles.splice(missile, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="background">
    <div id="missiles"></div>
    <div id="fiende"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.missile1 {
    width: 10px;
    height: 28px;
    background-image: url('missile1.png');
    position: absolute;
}

div.enemy {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url('enemy.png');
    position: absolute;
}
```

Some of the animation, it's basically the same after that.

```
@keyframes bevegelse {
0% {
    left: -230px;
    top: 0%;
}
5% {
    left: 250px;
    top: 0%;
}
10% {
    left: 250px;
    top: 40px;
}
15% {
    left: -230px;
    top: 40px;
}
```

When a missile hits the enemy, it destroys some other enemies, which the missile didn't hit. Sometimes it doesn't even destroy the randoms ones.

Comment: HTMLDivElement doesn't have a length property

Comment: @nickzoum Could you explain a bit more about that?

Comment: you need to declare your `friende` and `missiles` variables or pass them as arguments to `function collisionDetection`

Comment: @molamk So how and where do I do that?

Comment: @Ben You said `"fiende" and "missile" are div(s) in html.`. Then you are doing `fiende.length`. The JavaScript object for div doesn't have a length property.

Comment: @nickzoum But where do I add the length property?

Comment: I think you need to include your __relevant__ HTML in your question

Comment: @molamk I have added it now.

Comment: Hello Ben, perhaps you can use canvas to solve your problem (with an additional library like Phaser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in your loop.  You are stepping through the indices into the array, but also modifying the array as you go, so you may get confusing results.  This may or may not be the cause of your other issues (clearly this is not all of your code) however fixing this may help.

There are a number of ways to fix this.  My usual method is to count backwards through the array so that removing elements does not impact the locations of indices the loop is yet to visit.

```
function collisionDetection() {
    //because this loop is continued once the array is modified, count from the end
    for (var enemy = fiende.length-1; enemy >=0 ; enemy--) {
        //this loop exits when a clash is found, so count as normal
        for (var missile = 0; missile < missiles.length; missile++) {
            if (
                missiles[missile].left >= fiende[enemy].left &&
                missiles[missile].left <= (fiende[enemy].left + 50) &&
                missiles[missile].top <= (fiende[enemy].top + 50) &&
                missiles[missile].top >= fiende[enemy].top
            ) {
                fiende.splice(enemy, 1);
                missiles.splice(missile, 1);
                //the enemy has already been hit, exit and dont consider other missiles
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've made the assumption here that it is one missile gone per enemy.  If you want more than one missile to be destroyed, then remove the break and also count backwards in the inner loop.

---

Thank you for supplying a reference to your git code (see the comments below).

The above is an error in the code, however not one which is typically causing any problem.  The issue seems to be that when the enemies are animated the bullets don't hit them.  The problem here is that you are detecting collisions with your js code's view of the enemy location, but you are enhancing the animation with css animation.  If you wish to detect the collisions then you need to animate entirely in JS.

Try removing the css animation to verify you can hit the enemies.  Then if that works you need to do all the movement in js.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. It's one missile per enemy. Could you elaborate on how I can fix it, since I'm very new to js, so I need a bit more guidance.

Comment: See the code I posted above.  This fixes a bug in your code.  Note that this is not a js-specific issue but the more general problem of modifying an array while looping through it.

Comment: This may not sort exactly the bug you are seeing.  There is not really enough of your code to know for sure.

Comment: What more of the code do you need to help me find what is causing the trouble?

Comment: Try changing the loop to the code in my answer.  If that does not help then the minimum is usually enough code to actually have something that runs (e.g. on jsfiddle or similar) and demonstrates your problem.

Comment: e.g. some enemies in fixed positions, some missiles travelling towards them (so creation code for both and animation code for the missiles) plus the collision detection code so that we can see all the code responsible for the problem you describe.

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tm7k62qr/ It's missing some of the pictures.. However, here's my github link, where the pictures are included: https://belminh.github.io/Projekt_2/html/space_invaders.html It's still very early on.. so much can change.

Comment: Excellent.  I suggest you put that link in the main question, it helps a lot.

Comment: As far as I could tell the code seemed to be working.  I didn't have the images, so I set the background colours of the different elements, and as far as I could tell I could move the ship OK, fire bullets, and the right enemies were hit. fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0kq5muLh/

Comment: Then it might be something wrong with the pictures? Since when I shoot them(while they are moving), they either 1) don't hit the enemies, or 2) they hit the wrong enemies.

Comment: I still think the loop is not quite right, however it may not be causing problems.  I changed it here: https://jsfiddle.net/0kq5muLh/1/

Comment: Have you tested it out on the github link, since there I'm having some issues? On the jsfiddle link, it works good, but not on the github link. Even though it's the same code.

Comment: So I tested it without the animation, and it works perfectly. However, it doesn't work with the animation.

Comment: The animation has no error checking.  I had some errors on the console which may have broken your chain of calls.

Comment: That's somewhat strange, since on my end the errors are not showing at all in the console. Could you send me the error messages?

Comment: Hmmm, I can't get it to throw again.  It was an error with document.getElemnentById('pilot') which was odd as the element was in the DOM, unless it was a race condition with whatever was creating the elements in the first place.

Comment: I tried to just run the few rows of the animations, and it seems that the hitbox doesn't move with the animation. Hence, the broken hitbox when it's running with the animation. However, I have no clue on how to fix that.

Comment: yup, I just added a comment above in the answer.  You are mixing js and css animation, but the js has no imformation as to where the css has animated the enemies to at any given time.  I'm afraid you will need to turn off the css animation and do it all yourself if you want collision detection.   As suggested above in the comments to your question, another option would be to use a (typically canvas-based) framework which may do some of this for you.

Comment: So you're saying that must either animate it in js, or I can use canvas? I have little experience, and no experience using canvas. So is it possible to get some link(s) that would fit my code, and then I could modify it?

Comment: To animate in js, you could do the maths yourself or look for a library to help you (a 30s search found https://animejs.com/, I'm sure there are plenty of others).  Example framework for canvas animation: https://createjs.com/easeljs.  Again there are lots of others.  Personally I would have a go doing the maths for the animation myself, but it really depends on your preferences.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! It has helped a lot, I'm thinking to got the math route, so I'll be trying out animejs.com. But thanks again.